# RequestMapping value attribute as string variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this problem, I'm trying to put a `String` variable in the `value` attribute of `@RequestMapping` annotation:

```
private static final String PREVIEW = "/preview/anything";

...

@RequestMapping(value=PREVIEW, method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Could I do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can although IMHO it's less readable. You normally define a constant if you want to use it in many places but in this case I'd prefer to see the url mapping directly over the method.